# Como pegar o serial do monitor via código

Tags: .net, vb.net, vba, excel-vba, vbscript

Preciso levantar diversas informações de monitores via código, pesquisei um pouco e encontrei este link:
https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/vbs-scripts/vbs-script-get-monitor-serial-number-remotely/
O código em si funciona muito bem o problema é que no Windows 10 ele não me retorna nenhuma informação sobre o monitor.
Gostaria de saber se existe alguma outra maneira que eu possa levantar pelo menos o serial number do monitor por código, sem ser powershell.

Comment: Deve ser diferente no Windows 10 isso que precisa verificar ... não é uma boa então mexer com esse script ...

Comment: Pelo que entendi do código ele pega pelo registro do windows, no caminho: `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY\Default_Monitor`, se estudar isto é quase certo (é o que me parece) que vai conseguir criar um algoritimo razoavelmente mais simples que pegue os tais dados.

Comment: Votei para fechar, mas acho que talvez o caso desta pergunta seja razoavel, portanto estou votando para reabrir, eu até entendo que o autor não apresentou tentativa alguma, mas visto que já existe uma resposta e que a pergunta é bem objetivo (o que acho que ajuda muito), ela não tem muito o que melhorar e por isto me parece razoavel e util para futuros visitantes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Windows, recomendaria você a buscar essa informação utilizando [wmi](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-start-page).

Importe a referencia abaixo:

```
Imports System.Management
```

E busque o dado do serial utilizando a tabela [WMIMonitorID](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmicoreprov/wmimonitorid):

```
Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("root\WMI", "SELECT * FROM WMIMonitorID")
For Each queryObj As ManagementObject In searcher.Get()
    Dim serial() As UInt16 = queryObj("SerialNumberID")
Next
```